# Key Error 'Main' when trying an openweathermap python api tutorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, openweathermap

I'm currently trying to run through a tutorial of how to set up openweathermap via Python but i'm getting a KeyError and I was wondering if someone could help me out.

The error I am getting is KeyError: 'main'

In the actual code I have put in my API but have taken it out for obvious reasons.

```
api_key = ""


base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"


city_name = input("Enter city name : ") 


complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name 


response = requests.get(complete_url) 


x = response.json() 


if x["cod"] != "404": 

y = x["main"] 


current_temperature = y["temp"] 

current_pressure = y["pressure"] 


current_humidiy = y["humidity"] 


z = x["weather"] 

weather_description = z[0]["description"] 


print(" Temperature (in kelvin unit) = " +
                str(current_temperature) + 
      "\n atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = " +
                str(current_pressure) +
      "\n humidity (in percentage) = " +
                str(current_humidiy) +
      "\n description = " +
                str(weather_description)) 

else: 
    print(" City Not Found ")
```

Comment: Add `print(x)` output

Comment: Hi there :) sorry where did you mean for me to include print(x) in the code?

Comment: After `x = response.json() `

Comment: It seems to print out the weather information in JSON but still shows the KeyError.

Comment: Add the information; It does not have `main`

Comment: Oh sorry I see what you mean, it prints it all out in JSON and the only reason it was still giving an error is because of a small tweak I did. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
import requests

OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_APIKEY = '<your key>'

def get_weather_data_by_location( lat, long):
    url = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={long}&appid={OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_APIKEY}&units=metric'
    print(f"Getting data via {url}")
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()
    else:
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Getting Weather Data")
    print( get_weather_data_by_location( '22.300910042194783', '114.17070449064359') )
```

I have an beginners guide to open weather map which you can follow here: https://pythonhowtoprogram.com/get-weather-forecasts-and-show-it-on-a-chart-using-python-3/